# Create Api for file sharing

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been trying to develop an api to share files using node js. I've developed one but it explicitly requires sender to send data buffer of the file with its mimetype (example, application/pdf).

I was wondering if i could get any better solution then this. Im familiar with the busboy and express file-upload module. And I know busboy requires multipart/form-data to send a file but it also needs boundary with it , how do i define boundary if somebody have to send the file using postman ?

Comment: what do you mean by boundary ? you mean size of the uploaded file ?

Comment: @UsmanRana you know uploading files with even html requires multipart/form-data enc-type in form. and boundary is there to make http req readable for server. for example 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryusnjDLmBrZEIllAP